# Minify bash command with arguments

Tags: bash, shell-script, tmux, alias, ping

Want to minify bash command using arguments.

I am often checking the internet provider's and other [Free and Public DNS Servers](https://www.lifewire.com/free-and-public-dns-servers-2626062) with the code below running in [tmux](https://github.com/tmux/tmux), but wondering, how this can be minified, to make it much nicer? Any ideas?

```bash
tmux neww ; 
 tmux split-window -v 'ping 8.8.8.8' \;
 split-window -v 'ping 1.1.1.1' \;
 \select-pane -t 1 \;
 split-window -h 'ping 8.8.4.4' \;
 \select-pane -t 3 \;
 split-window -h 'ping 1.0.0.1' \;
 \select-pane -t 0 \;
 split-window -h 'ping 76.76.2.5' \;
 split-window -v 'ping 76.76.19.19' \;
 \select-pane -t 0 \;
 split-window -v 'ping 208.67.220.220' \;
 \select-pane -t 0 \;
 split-window -v 'ping 208.67.222.222'
```

### Desired solution

```bash
$ pp
```

if no arguments defined, execute `tmux neww \; split-window …` with predefined IP addresses.

```bash
$ pp 1.1.1.1 1.0.0.1
```

with single or multiple arguments, run `tmux neww \; split-window …` with the defined IP address(es) (ideally along with the predefined IP addresses).

### Trying to define in `~/.bash_aliases`,

Here is the actual code

```bash
# check multiple round-trip time (RTT)

dnscheck() { # compare multiple DNS servers using `ping`
  tmux split-window -v 'ping 8.8.8.8' \; split-window -v 'ping 1.1.1.1' \; \select-pane -t 1 \; split-window -h 'ping 8.8.4.4' \; \select-pane -t 3 \; split-window -h 'ping 1.0.0.1' \; \select-pane -t 0 \; split-window -h 'ping 76.76.2.5' \; split-window -v 'ping 76.76.19.19' \; \select-pane -t 0 \; split-window -v 'ping 208.67.220.220' \; \select-pane -t 0  \; split-window -v 'ping 208.67.222.222' ; exit
}

mping() { # multiple pings
 [[ -z ${1} ]] && tmux neww dnscheck; # run dnscheck() if no argument
 tmux neww ping ${1} \; split-window -v ping ${2} \; split-window -h -t 0 ping ${3} \; split-window -h -t 2 ping ${4}
}
alias tp="tmux neww -n pingR ping 0 -c 3 \; select-window -t pingR ; dnscheck" # Expected to run dnscheck in new window
alias pp="mping"
```

Currently

1. `tp` executes `dnscheck` in a new *tmux window* properly (with a bit of hack: `ping 0 -c 3`)
2. `pp 0 0 0 0` does the job as well

but can't figure out how these can be merged to have a default value for `pp` to execute `tp`

Comment: In the function, you've got `${1}` in single quotes which would keep it from expanding. Does `"ping ${1}"` do what you want? Unrelated but `[[ -z ${1} ]]` is the same as `[[ ! -n ${1} ]]`.

Comment: thank you @frabjous, on step closer now with the double quotes, and `-z` +1 ;)

Comment: I think you can solve that by making an alias